# SequenceInputStream не получает данные со второго потока

Tags: java, filestream

Надо из двух потоков прочитать данные и записать в один.

```
 FileOutputStream file1 = new FileOutputStream("D:\\file1.txt");     
 SequenceInputStream sequance = new SequenceInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\file3.txt"), new FileInputStream("D:\\file2.txt"));

        int size = sequance.available();
        int reading = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        if(sequance.available() > 0)
        {
            reading = sequance.read(buffer, 0, size);
            file1.write(buffer, 0, reading);
        }

        sequance.close();
        file1.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Читает только из первого потока, если потоки в конструкторе поменять местами, то опять читает только из первого потока (в результирующем файле данные только из первого потока, делала debug, переменная size равна кол-ву символов в первом потоке). В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашим камнем преткновения является строка `int size = sequance.available();` А если быть точнее сам метод `.available()` он на сколько я помню возвращает колличество доступных бит в одном / текущем потоке ну а что далее происходит в общем-то должно быть понятно. Буфер мал для данных из двух файлов

UPD:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from the current underlying input stream without
>   blocking by the next invocation of a method for the current underlying
>   input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another
>   thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but
>   may read or skip fewer bytes.

пример Вашего кода (рабочий) без стримов и буферов

```
FileOutputStream file1 = new FileOutputStream("/home/peter/git/1.txt", true);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            SequenceInputStream sequance = new SequenceInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(new File("/home/peter/git/3.txt")),
                    new FileInputStream("/home/peter/git/2.txt"));
            int reading = 0;
            while ((reading = sequance.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.println(reading);
                file1.write(reading);
            }

            sequance.close();
            file1.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sequance.read(buffer, 0, size);
```

читает только порцию данных, длиной не менее 1 и не более размера буфера. Сколько конкретно - на усмотрение реализации. Чтобы прочитать все, всегда необходим цикл.

Между прочим, [available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) дает лишь оценку, а не точный размер имеющихся данных. И эта оценка вам не нужна вовсе.

Comment: С циклом тоже пробовала, вместо if, та же ситуация. Ошибка проявляется уже на строчке расчета переменной size.